# How to load a Java Card applet into the Samsung S8 embedded secure element

Tags: javacard, globalplatform, secure-element

I would like to use the Open Mobile API (also called OMAPI, available on Android 9) to access a Java Card applet I developed from an Android application. I would like the applet to be stored on the Samsung S8 embedded secure element (Gemalto eSE).

I have already checked that this secure element is visible through the Open Mobile API on a S8 with Android 9. But I have no idea about how I could load the applet I made in the secure element.

Has anybody already tried to do that, either on a Samsung device or on a device embedding a Gemalto eSE ?

Answer (score 2):

You need the keys from Samsung.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about these keys? Are they needed for authentication for ISD?